# Ripple API #wallet_propose not working, given error "Forbidden"

Tags: ripple

I'm sure the way of calling the methods is correct because I could call other methods successfully.

```
curl -X POST -d "{ \"method\" : \"wallet_propose\" , \"params\" : [ { \"passphrase\" : \"something\" } ] }" http://s1.ripple.com:51234
```

response:

> Forbidden

when i can get a response successfully

```
  nishidaryu$ curl -X POST -d "{\"method\":\"account_info\",\"params\":[{\"account\":\"rHb9CJAWyB4rj91VRWn96DkukG4bwdtyTh\"}],\"id\":\"jsonrpc\"}" http://s1.ripple.com:51234

  {"result":{"account_data":{"Account":"rHb9CJAWyB4rj91VRWn96DkukG4bwdtyTh","Balance":"3732064450","Flags":1703936,"LedgerEntryType":"AccountRoot","OwnerCount":1,"PreviousTxnID":"098F1AD803521822983FE9C53213A27D19891D664BB3A1701FC473B1AF4EEEE2","PreviousTxnLgrSeq":37696835,"RegularKey":"rBmVUQNF6tJy4cLvoKdPXb4BNqKBk5JY1Y","Sequence":44196,"TransferRate":1220000000,"index":"2B6AC232AA4C4BE41BF49D2459FA4A0347E1B543A4C92FCEE0821C0201E2E9A8"},"ledger_current_index":37746144,"status":"success","validated":false}}
```

Any idea?

Comment: This is a terribly vague question; how are people meant to guess why your code is not working when you didn't show any of it? See the Help Centre: _"Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."_

Comment: I edited to follow that.  underscore_d

Comment: did you do a compare from your curl attempt with a authentic attempt using fiddler or wireshark?

Comment: I did check it online and I got

Response Header


HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 05 Apr 2018 16:09:40 +0000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 114
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Server: ripple-json-rpc/rippled-0.90.1
 
Response Body

Unable to parse request: * Line 1, Column 1
  A valid JSON document must be either an array or an object value.

Comment: your not understanding me, you should have a working example and a none working example in text and compare them with wireshark or some networking sniffing tool

Comment: Okay, but can't I use terminal to show you  normally?

Comment: links to pastebin usually work good

Comment: I guess they forbid us to generate accounts online cuz there's a concern that the secret keys will be stolen, so I will try ripple-lib or rippled client  thanks anyway!